# When i try to do a gcloud components update from my local machine, the process seems to hang. How do i update google cloud sdk?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I tried installing a new version, however that also takes me the components update route.

The component update[image] route seems to be forever "creating update staging area"

Comment: did you ever get a good acceptable answer to this. i have the same problem. thanks!

Comment: Hi, is this update gonna affect any of our project?

Answer (score 4):

i just waited and it took ~15 minutes. maybe take a break and come back. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you run 'gcloud components update' while any of files is in use,
update would not be finished and gcloud would never end the update.

make sure you don't have more windows open.

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn off the docker off for the duration of the update.

Answer (score 0):

It can take up to 30 minutes on my computer now.